# Azure App Service CORS setting not working from ARM

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I am deploying a web app using ARM. There are no errors with the deployment and everything deploys fine EXCEPT my CORS settings. Below is my siteConfig definition for the app service.

```
"siteConfig": {
                "AlwaysOn": true,
                "linuxFxVersion": "NODE|16-lts",
                "appCommandLine": "startup command goes here",
                "cors": {
                    "allowedOrigins": "[parameters('backEndCORSOrigins')]",
                    "supportCredentials": false
                },
                "appSettings": "ENV_VARS_GO_HERE",
                "scmIpSecurityRestrictions": "[parameters('backEndSCMIPRestrictions')]",
                "IpSecurityRestrictions": "[parameters('backEndIPRestrictions')]"
            }
```

And my parameter setting.

```
"backEndCORSOrigins": {
        "value": "https://hostname.azurewebsites.net"
    },
```

When I deply this ARM templte these is NO CORS setting applied on the app service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the ARM api version you are using but according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#corssettings), the property `allowedOrigins` accept an array of string:

```bicep
"cors": {
  "allowedOrigins": [
    "[parameters('backEndCORSOrigins')]"
  ],
  "supportCredentials": false
}
```

Comment: Yep this was it, I was passing a comma delimited string. Changed it to an array of string and its good now. Thanks.